# How to know which project is using another project during runtime

Tags: c#

I have two projects (A and B) using a common shared project (C). In this shared project I need to know which project A or B is using C during runtime.

I have tried to find out if the caller object belongs to A or B but I still don't know if this is possible or if there is a better solution.

Comment: Sounds like an  [XY problem](http://xyproblem.info) to me.

Comment: That's a design smell. A library shouldn't have to know who calls it. If you want to invoke different _behavior_, you could do so using a boolean in the method you call: `isProjectA`. You can then rename it according to the use case, so instead of `isProjectA` you could name it `calculatePriceExcludingSalesTax`, or after whatever different behavior you want.

Comment: Is project B a different application or is this code that all compiles and runs together?  We need to see the project outline and know what A, B, and C represent.  This typically isn't something you need to worry about though.